# Community Wiki by default?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I've edited [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14962/5) [12 times](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/14962/revisions), each time trying to improve it in some way. Suddenly it is marked as community wiki. Did a mod do this, or did I accidentally do this (by clicking on community wiki inadvertently), or, as I suspect, did I do this as a consequence of hitting some magic number of edits (and was that number 12, or did I just not notice it earlier)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posts that are edited 10 times by the OP are automatically converted to community wiki.

From [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

> Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.
> - The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.
> - .......

Comment: Is there a way to reclaim it? I was hoping to use my final version as a Purim Derashah this year. I guess I could just always go look at previous versions and copy the one I like best.

Comment: @SethJ How does CW prevent you from using it as a Purim Derasha?

Comment: @SethJ, I don't see why not to dewikify it. Done. Try to combine smaller edits into larger ones in the future.

Comment: I can't just casually print the most recent version if someone else has been editing it.

Comment: @msh210 How do you do that?

Comment: @SethJ True, but the fact that it's not CW doesn't prevent anyone with 500+ rep from editing it at anytime. Moot point now. :-D

Comment: @SethJ It's a moderator ability. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/168660

Comment: True. Thanks, both of you.